# Does a spaceship need Affects Others on its Immunites to keep its passengers safe?

Tags: character-creation, vehicles, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, immunities

Say one is making a vehicle to travel through a particularly hostile environment, such as space. Naturally, one would grant the vehicle the Immunity applied to the various dangers of the environment, such a Immunity to vacuum and radiation in our example. However, say the vehicle is being designed to carry passengers through the aforementioned hostile environment.

Does a passenger vehicle need to apply 'affects other' to all its Immunities to protect its occupants as well, or is the effect always applied to passengers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In much the same way as you don't need to specify "People don't recognize my hero out-of-costume", you don't need to specifically say, "The motorcycle can carry a passenger" or "The spaceship has a life-support system."

The [D20 HeroSRD](http://www.d20herosrd.com/7-gadgets-gear/vehicles/) (which includes the Open Game Content from M&M 3E) says this about vehicles:

> #### Vehicles and Environments
>
> A vehicle is assumed to provide the
> necessary life support for its passengers for the environments it is
> equipped to move through. So, for example, an aquatic vehicle is
> assumed to be water-tight and have its own oxygen supply, while a
> space vehicle is assumed to provide a safe, breathable environment,
> and even gravity. These are part of the vehicle’s descriptors and have
> no point cost. The GM may wish to permit the lack of such
> environmental systems as a Quirk on the vehicle’s cost or a
> complication in play. Certainly the disruption of such systems
> constitutes a complication!
>
> Immunity to environments or other effects not normally part of the
> vehicle’s mode(s) of movement is acquired as a power for the vehicle,
> typically Affects Others and Others Only for a net +0 modifier,
> protecting everyone inside the vehicle.

So, no.  You don't need to specifically buy the obvious stuff for your super-vehicle.  Non-obvious stuff, like the fact that the vehicle also has an AI Pilot that can remotely hack other ships?  ***That*** you have to pay points for.